# Regular expression in rename Unix command

Tags: regex, unix, rename

I am trying to rename some files and am pretty new to regular expressions. I know how to do this the long way, but I am trying some code golf to shorten it up.

My file:

```
abc4800_12_S200_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

My goal:

```
abc4800_12_R1.fastq.gz
```

Right now I have a two-step process for renaming it:

```
rename 's/_S[0-9]+//g' *gz
rename 's/_001//g' *gz
```

But I was trying to shorten this into one single line to clean it up in one go.

I was trying to use a regular expression to skip over the parts in between, but I don’t know if that is actually a possibility in this function.

```
rename 's/_S[0-9]+_*?_001//g' *gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a capture group to preserve the middle part of the segment you're replacing.

```
rename 's/_S\d+_(.*)_001/_$1/' *gz
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try the following `rename` command. I am using the `-n` option here which is a dry run for command. Once you are *happy* with the output (like how files are going to rename if we run actual code), remove the `-n` option from the following `rename` code.

```
rename -n 's/(^[^_]*_[^_]*)_[^_]*(_[^_]*)[^.]*(\..*$)/$1$2$3/' *.gz
```

The output will be as follows:

```
rename(abc4800_12_S200_R1_001.fastq.gz, abc4800_12_R1.fastq.gz)
```

***Explanation:***

```
(^[^_]*_[^_]*)  ## Creating the 1st capturing group which captures everything from starting to just before 2nd occurrence of _ here.
_[^_]*          ## Matching (without a capturing group) _ then just before the next occurrence of _ here.
(_[^_]*)        ## Creating the 2nd capturing group here which matches _, followed by before the next occurrence of _ here.
[^.]*           ## Matching everything just before dot comes (not capturing here).
(\..*$)         ## Creating the 3rd capturing group which has a dot till the end of line in it.
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on capture groups! I knew they were a thing, but was having trouble getting them to work in this instance. This helps a lot by using several, so I can see in more detail how they can be used. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to replace two parts in the string with nothing. Use the alternation operator. It will match the left or the right side; replacing any match with the same replacement string (i.e. nothing):

```
rename 's/_S[0-9]+|_001//g' *gz
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is a cool trick. I was thinking of using a capture group like in the examples above but was having issues with that. I didn't know about this function, thanks for the lesson.